# Как правильно восстановить систему с помощью перезапуска компонентов (почему компонент для тех-же входных данных, не должен снова упасть)?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Вопрос не столько про язык Erlang или Elixir, сколько про применяемую в них модель акторов.
Допустим у меня есть компонент, в который постоянно поступают данные. В какой-то момент произошел отказ. Следуя философии Erlang, я перезапускаю компонент, подаю в него снова те-же данные и... ожидаю какого-то другого результата? Так я понял идею, изложеннную Роландом Куном в его "Реактивных шаблонах проектирования". Он называет это "Допустимый отказ". Может что не так понял.
Компонент действительно может не упасть при тех-же входных данных. Например, в ходе работы где-то была утечка памяти, а после перезапуска, нет никакой утечки. Но скорее всего, это говорит о наличии состояния у компонента (у акторов ведь есть скрытое состояние). Но тогда получается, что компонент после перезапуска отработает неправильно, ведь он не просто так создавал состояние втечение всего этого времени. При перезапуске все накопленные (и, видимо, нужные) знания о предыдущих итерациях пропадут. Или такой подход справедлив только для тех отказов, которые возникают от неправильного освобождения ресурсов и никакого сотояния нет?
В моем скудоумном представлении дела обстоят так. Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Окей, может пригодится будущим поколениям. Насколько я понял, я изначально не правильно понял смысл такого подхода к обеспечению отказоустойчивости. Пример - если упавшему компоненту больше не доступен какой-то ресурс, он должен быть заново поднят супервайзером, но со ссылкой на другой ресурс, кэш, или реплику данного ресурса. Ни кто и не предлагает поднимать компоненты с теми-же входными данными. Просто контроль корректности данных переносится на уровень выше.